# How to fix " 'float' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

Hello I have an issue with my code :

```
xor_inputs = [(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0)]
xor_outputs = [(0.0,), (1.0), (1.0), (0.0)]

def eval_genomes(genomes, config):
    for genomes_id, genome in genomes:
        genome.fitness = 4.0
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(genome, config)
        for xi, xo in zip(xor_inputs, xor_outputs):
            output = net.activate(xi)
            genome.fitness -= (output[0] - xo[0])**2
```

When I run my file I have :

> " genome.fitness -= (output[0] - xo[0])**2
>
> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable "

Can you help me ? Thank you !

Comment: Did you print out what these variables contain? Did they contain what you thought they would?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xor_outputs = [(0.0,), (1.0), (1.0), (0.0)]
```

The first element in this list is a tuple with a single float because of the trailing comma. However, the rest of them are floats.

You don't really need tuples here, though. You can just do

```
xor_outputs = [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
```

Then change `output[0]` to just `output`:

```
genome.fitness -= (output - xo[0])**2
```

Note that tracking down errors like this is a large part of being a computer programmer. I suggest that you read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for a lot of tips that will help you track down problems like this. These tools won't always solve the problem, but they can help you find the reason for it.

Comment: I'm going to try.

Comment: Why I can switch to 

genome.fitness -= (output - xo[0])**2
 ?

Comment: @MrRex Because `output` will be a number instead of a tuple if you make the change to `xor_outputs` that I suggest. You need to learn about the fundamental data types in Python, especially the difference between basic types like floats and ints and more complex types like lists, tuples, and dicts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what any of your values are, or what your code is doing, but either output or xo is a float value, and not an array value like you think it is.